# Files opened on an external device being transferred to a hidden folder

Tags: windows, windows-11, temporary-files

When I connected my phone to my Windows 11 PC and opened a file in it, before it opened, I briefly saw a dialog box saying that it was being downloaded to "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\SOMERANDOMSTRING". I ran disk cleanup and restarted the computer, yet the files remained and I had to delete them manually. Strangely, I cannot see these folders in InetCache even with "Show Hidden Files" on.

I assume this has happened many times before and a lot of space must be taken up this way. How do I remove these files automatically? How can I make these folders visible in InetCache without knowing the addresses beforehand?

Comment: You can’t. Disk Cleanup wouldn’t delete temporary files like that until they were a specific age. If this file was opened by say Office you can simply change the temporary folder to something else.

Comment: One was a pdf opened by Sumatra Reader and the other was a video opened by VLC. What do you mean when you say you can't. Wouldn't these files pile up and take up your storage space?

Comment: But they would eventually be cleaned up